# Component that reacts on data changed from the store

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have a React/Flux web app and want to follow the architecture best practices:

[image]

I will focus on one view for my question, the component used to insert/update an entity (a User in occurrence).

Everything is working with this code, but the core of my question is about the `onUserDetailChanged` function in my `AdminUserDetail` component, which I find too contrived and confusing.

### Core of my question

I would like to refactor this code found in my component:

```
// ALL OF THIS IS UGLY
onUserDetailChanged: function() {
    var data = AdminUserDetailStore.getData();
    GuiHelper.blockGuiLoading(false);

    // Check first if there is a feedback message
    if (typeof data.FeedbackMessage !== 'undefined') {
        if (data.FeedbackMessage === ActionConstants.ERROR) {
            // Unexpected error
            GuiHelper.unexpectedError();
        }
        else if (data.FeedbackMessage === ActionConstants.SUCCESS) {
            // User saved successfully
            GuiHelper.infoDialog(BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS, LanguageLoader.langDict.msgUserSaved);
        }
    }
    // If there is no feedback message, check for errors
    else {
        if (data.Errors !== null && data.Errors.length > 0) {
            // Errors
            GuiHelper.infoDialog(BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER, GuiHelper.renderErrors(data.Errors));
        }
        else {
            // No errors, data changed (either from initial load or from user input)
            this.setState({ entity: data.Data });

            // Load the user permissions if required
            // (CAN I PLACE THIS CODE ELSEWHERE THAN IN THIS FUNCTION?)
            var userPermissions = AdminUserDetailPermissionsStore.getData().Data;
            if (this.state.entity.Id !== 0 && typeof userPermissions === 'undefined') {
                this.loadUserPermissions(data.Data.Username);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

What I don't like about this architecture is that all the api calls (`getUserDetail(userId)`, `getUserDetailPermissions(username)`, `postUserDetail(requestData)`) end up calling this function and I find it confusing how to notify the user about the result of the API call. Also, this function is even called on every data change caused by user input so I find  things are all mixed up.

The possible outcomes all supported by this contrived code:

- `getUserDetail(userId)` can end in `SUCCESS` with data or `ERROR` when an unexpected error arises (e.g. the api server is not responding)
- `getUserDetailPermissions(username)` can end in `SUCCESS` with data or `ERROR` when an unexpected error arises (e.g. the api server is not responding)
- `postUserDetail(requestData)` is a bit more complex since there are server validations on the data posted. It can end in `SUCCESS` or `ERROR` as the other calls, but it can also return a list of validation errors which must be displayed to the user.

Could I, for example, use different `onChange` functions to distinguish from each API call type and from a change in data caused by user input?

**WebApiClient.js**

```
import request from 'superagent';
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;

module.exports = {
    get: function (url) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            request
                .get(url)
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    if (err !== null) {
                        reject();
                    }
                    else {
                        if (res.status === 404) {
                            reject();
                        }
                        else {
                            resolve(JSON.parse(res.text));
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
    },

    post: function (url, data) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            request
                .post(url)
                .send(data)
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    if (err !== null) {
                        reject();
                    }
                    else {
                        if (res.status === 404) {
                            reject();
                        }
                        else {
                            resolve(JSON.parse(res.text));
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
    }
}
```

**ActionsCreator.js**

```
var Dispatcher = require('./Dispatcher');
var ActionConstants = require('./ActionConstants');
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
var Api = require('../Util/WebApiClient');

var ActionCreator = {
    apiServer: 'http://localhost:55010/api',

    getUserDetail: function (userId) {
        Api.get(this.apiServer + '/v1/User/' + userId)
            .then(function (responseData) { Dispatcher.handleAction({ actionType: ActionConstants.GET_USER, data: responseData }); })
            .catch(function () { Dispatcher.handleAction({ actionType: ActionConstants.ERROR }); });
    },

    getUserDetailPermissions: function (username) {
        Api.get(this.apiServer + '/v1/Permission/ForUser?username=' + username)
            .then(function (responseData) { Dispatcher.handleAction({ actionType: ActionConstants.GET_USERPERMISSIONS, data: responseData }); })
            .catch(function () { Dispatcher.handleAction({ actionType: ActionConstants.ERROR }); });
    },

    postUserDetail: function (requestData) {
        Api.post(this.apiServer + '/v1/User/', requestData)
            .then(function (responseData) { Dispatcher.handleAction({ actionType: ActionConstants.POST_USER, data: responseData }); })
            .catch(function () { Dispatcher.handleAction({ actionType: ActionConstants.ERROR }); });
    }
};

module.exports = ActionCreator;
```

**ActionConstants.js**

```
module.exports = {
  GET_USER: 'GET_USER',
  GET_USERPERMISSIONS: 'GET_USERPERMISSIONS',
  POST_USER: 'POST_USER',

  ERROR: 'ERROR',
  SUCCESS: 'SUCCESS'
};
```

**Dispatcher.js**

```
var Dispatcher = require('flux').Dispatcher;

// Create dispatcher instance
var Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

// Convenience method to handle dispatch requests
Dispatcher.handleAction = function(action) {
    this.dispatch({
        source: 'VIEW_ACTION',
        action: action
    });
}

module.exports = Dispatcher;
```

**AdminUserDetailStore.js**

```
var Dispatcher = require('../Core/Dispatcher');
var ActionConstants = require('../Core/ActionConstants');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var assign = require('object-assign');

var CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

var AdminUserDetailStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    data: {},

    // Called after the initial GET to load the initial User entity
    // or from user input
    setData: function(data, doEmitChange) {
        this.data = data;

        if (typeof doEmitChange !== 'undefined' && doEmitChange) {
            this.emitChange();
        }
    },

    // Called from a POST when trying to save the User entity
    // or when getting an unexpected error (e.g. api server unavailable)
    setFeedbackMessage: function(data, message) {
        if (typeof message !== 'undefined')
            this.data.FeedbackMessage = message;
        else {
            if (data.Errors.length > 0)
                this.data.Errors = data.Errors;
            else
                this.data.FeedbackMessage = ActionConstants.SUCCESS;
        }
    },

    emitChange: function () {
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    },

    addChangeListener: function (callback) {
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },

    removeChangeListener: function (callback) {
        this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },

    getData: function () {
        return this.data;
    }
});

Dispatcher.register(function(payload) {
    var action = payload.action;

    switch(action.actionType) {
        case ActionConstants.ERROR:
            // Force a feedback message
            AdminUserDetailStore.setFeedbackMessage(null, ActionConstants.ERROR);
            break;
        case ActionConstants.GET_USER:
            AdminUserDetailStore.setData(action.data);
            break;
        case ActionConstants.POST_USER:
            // Check for errors wthin the data object and set a SUCCESS feedback message if none are found
            AdminUserDetailStore.setFeedbackMessage(action.data);
            break;
        default:
            return true;
    }

    AdminUserDetailStore.emitChange();
    return true;
});

module.exports = AdminUserDetailStore;
```

**AdminUserDetail.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ActionCreator from '../../Core/ActionCreator';
import ActionConstants from '../../Core/ActionConstants';

import AdminUserDetailStore  from '../../Stores/AdminUserDetailStore';
import AdminUserDetailPermissionsStore  from '../../Stores/AdminUserDetailPermissionsStore';

import LanguageLoader from '../../Util/LanguageLoader';
import GuiHelper from '../../Util/GuiHelper';
import BootstrapDialog from 'bootstrap-dialog';

import blockUI from '../../../Content/js/jquery.blockUI.js';

import {AgGridReact} from 'ag-grid-react';
import BoolCellEditor from '../AgGrid/BoolCellEditor';

$ = window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

var AdminUserDetail = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            entity: {
                Id: 0,
                Username: '',
                Email: ''
            },

            userPermissions: null,
            userPermissionsColumns: [
                { headerName: LanguageLoader.langDict.lblRole, field: 'role' },
                { headerName: LanguageLoader.langDict.lblPermission, field: 'permission' },
                { headerName: LanguageLoader.langDict.lblDescription, field: 'description', width:600 }
            ],

            gridOptions: {
                context: this,
                singleClickEdit: true,
                enableColResize: true,
                onGridReady: function(event) {
                    //event.api.autoSizeColumns();
                },
            },
        };
    },

    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return { };
    },

    componentWillMount: function () {
        AdminUserDetailStore.addChangeListener(this.onUserDetailChanged);
        AdminUserDetailPermissionsStore.addChangeListener(this.onUserDetailPermissionsChanged);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function () {
        AdminUserDetailStore.removeChangeListener(this.onUserDetailChanged);
        AdminUserDetailPermissionsStore.removeChangeListener(this.onUserDetailPermissionsChanged);
    },

    // ALL OF THIS IS UGLY
    onUserDetailChanged: function() {
        var data = AdminUserDetailStore.getData();
        GuiHelper.blockGuiLoading(false);

        // Check first if there is a feedback message
        if (typeof data.FeedbackMessage !== 'undefined') {
            if (data.FeedbackMessage === ActionConstants.ERROR) {
                // Unexpected error
                GuiHelper.unexpectedError();
            }
            else if (data.FeedbackMessage === ActionConstants.SUCCESS) {
                // User saved successfully
                GuiHelper.infoDialog(BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS, LanguageLoader.langDict.msgUserSaved);
            }
        }
        // If there is no feedback message, check for errors
        else {
            if (data.Errors !== null && data.Errors.length > 0) {
                // Errors
                GuiHelper.infoDialog(BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER, GuiHelper.renderErrors(data.Errors));
            }
            else {
                // No errors, data changed (either from initial load or from user input)
                this.setState({ entity: data.Data });

                // Load the user permissions if required
                // (CAN I PLACE THIS CODE ELSEWHERE THAN IN THIS FUNCTION?)
                var userPermissions = AdminUserDetailPermissionsStore.getData().Data;
                if (this.state.entity.Id !== 0 && typeof userPermissions === 'undefined') {
                    this.loadUserPermissions(data.Data.Username);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    onUserDetailPermissionsChanged: function() {
        var data = AdminUserDetailPermissionsStore.getData();
        GuiHelper.blockGuiLoading(false);

        if (typeof data.FeedbackMessage !== 'undefined' && data.FeedbackMessage === ActionConstants.ERROR) {
            GuiHelper.unexpectedError();
        }
        else {
            var userPermissions = data.Data.map(function(i, idx) {
                return { role: i.Key, permission: i.Value, description: LanguageLoader.langDict['P_' + i.Value] };
            });
            this.setState({ userPermissions: userPermissions });
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        // Initialize/clear the stores
        AdminUserDetailStore.setData({});
        AdminUserDetailPermissionsStore.setData({});

        if (this.props.id !== null) {
            GuiHelper.blockGuiLoading(true);
            ActionCreator.getUserDetail(this.props.id);
        }
    },

    loadUserPermissions :function(username) {
        GuiHelper.blockGuiLoading(true);
        ActionCreator.getUserDetailPermissions(username);
    },

    saveUser: function () {
        GuiHelper.blockGuiLoading(true);
        ActionCreator.postUserDetail(this.state.entity);
    },

    onUsernameChanged: function(e) {
        var entity = this.state.entity;
        entity.Username = e.target.value;
        AdminUserDetailStore.setData({ Errors: null, Data: entity }, true);
    },

    onEmailChanged: function(e) {
        var entity = this.state.entity;
        entity.Email = e.target.value;
        AdminUserDetailStore.setData({ Errors: null, Data: entity }, true);
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{LanguageLoader.langDict.lblUserDetail}</h1>

                <form>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-9 col-centered">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="userUsername">{LanguageLoader.langDict.lblUsername}</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="userUsername" value={this.state.entity.Username} placeholder={LanguageLoader.langDict.lblUsername} onChange={this.onUsernameChanged} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-9 col-centered">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="userEmail">{LanguageLoader.langDict.lblEmailAddress}</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="userEmail" value={this.state.entity.Email} placeholder={LanguageLoader.langDict.lblEmail} onChange={this.onEmailChanged} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div className={this.state.userPermissions === null ? 'hidden' : ''}>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-9 col-centered">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>{LanguageLoader.langDict.lblPermissionsFromRole}</label>
                                <div style={{height: 400}} className="ag-fresh">
                                    <AgGridReact gridOptions={this.state.gridOptions} columnDefs={this.state.userPermissionsColumns} rowData={this.state.userPermissions} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = AdminUserDetail;
```

Finally, from the server-side, an api call always return an object with 2 properties:

```
public dynamic Data { get; set; }
public ICollection<string> Errors { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your `if`s:

> ```
> .end(function (err, res) {
>     if (err !== null) {
>         reject();
>     }
>     else {
>         if (res.status === 404) {
>             reject();
>         }
>         else {
>             resolve(JSON.parse(res.text));
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```

Notice how you call `reject`()` for two paths.  This can be simplified to:

```
.end(function (err, res) {
    if (err !== null || res.status === 404) {
        reject();
    }
    else {
        resolve(JSON.parse(res.text));
    }
});
```

This is a lot simpler to parse.  Alternatively, if you still want to have the separate cases, I would use `else if` instead of nesting them:

```
.end(function (err, res) {
    if (err !== null) {
        reject();
    }
    else if (res.status === 404) {
        reject();
    }
    else {
        resolve(JSON.parse(res.text));
    }
});
```

---

Your bracing isn't consistent:

> ```
> setFeedbackMessage: function(data, message) {
>     if (typeof message !== 'undefined')
>         this.data.FeedbackMessage = message;
>     else {
>         if (data.Errors.length > 0)
>             this.data.Errors = data.Errors;
>         else
>             this.data.FeedbackMessage = ActionConstants.SUCCESS;
>     }
> }
> ```

You should always use braces, but even more important is always being consistent.

---

In this function, your return value is meaningless:

> ```
> Dispatcher.register(function(payload) {
>     var action = payload.action;
>
>     switch(action.actionType) {
>         case ActionConstants.ERROR:
>             // Force a feedback message
>             AdminUserDetailStore.setFeedbackMessage(null, ActionConstants.ERROR);
>             break;
>         case ActionConstants.GET_USER:
>             AdminUserDetailStore.setData(action.data);
>             break;
>         case ActionConstants.POST_USER:
>             // Check for errors wthin the data object and set a SUCCESS feedback message if none are found
>             AdminUserDetailStore.setFeedbackMessage(action.data);
>             break;
>         default:
>             return true;
>     }
>
>     AdminUserDetailStore.emitChange();
>     return true;
> });
> ```

You never return `false`, so returning `true` doesn't give you any meaningful information.  I would make this a `void` method and just `return`.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will make use of all these improvements, however they are not tackling the core of my question :)

Comment: Yep, I left that for other reviewers as I'm not a JS person.  Also, the rules for the site are any and every point is up for discussion, even if some points are more equal than others.

Comment: And your pertinent intervention is appreciated, thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome.  Glad to help.